cgo : running 2 or more dynamic link GO from C executable
run C exe that linked with 2 GO dynamic link shared object .
text
"*Go code linked into, and called from, a non-Go program
In this mode Go code acts as a library that may be called by a non-Go program.  A single Go library will be an archive, a .a file on Unix, that will act as a unit, providing a C style API.  If some of the execution modes below are implemented, then it will also be possible to implement this as a shared library, a .so file on Unix.
This mode supports people who must work with large existing programs, especially in C/C++ but possibly in other languages as well.  It permits them to extend those existing programs with new packages written in Go.
In the Go 1.5 release this mode is implemented, using a .a file, for most Unix systems*."
it is already supported.
when I run sample program,  that load 2 GO sharead object, that code behave unexpcted and crash

go

/*
#include <stdio.h>
*/
import "C"
import (
   "reflect"
   "unsafe"   
)

func main() {
}

//export CallAddCheckA
func CallAddCheckA( {
    fmt.PrintLn("hello A")
}



go

package main

/*
#include <stdio.h>
*/
import "C"
import (
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"   
)

func main() {
}

//export CallAddCheckB
func CallAddCheckB( {
    fmt.PrintLn("hello B")
}



c

#include "../mainA.h"
#include "../mainB.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "stdio.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
 
    CallAddCheckA();
    CallAddCheckB();
}

when I call CallAddCheckB() from new  thread,  all works good

Please provide a minimal reproducible example (with a Makefile or something similar) and debugging details (like the stack trace at the crash). Also, I'm not sure merging two separately compiled Go libraries together is a good idea, they might contain parts that are incompatible. Use a single Go library, when possible.
